# elastic search upsert array element Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I want to add/update the new emp and empTrans in elastic serach but I am not sure what could be correct query to upsert(add and update) the record in NodeJs

```
{
  id: '1',
  emp: [{
    empId: 'uuid + phonennumebr1',
    empDetail: {
      name: '',
    },
  },
  {
    empId: 'uuid + phonennumebr2',
    empDetail: {
      name: '',
    },
  }],
  empTrans: {
    date: '',
  },
}

when I use below query to update emp. It did not work.i also used same query to update Emp Transaction attribute but it dod not work

client.update({
    index: 'test',
    type: 'emp',
    id: empId,
    body: {
        script: {
            inline: "ctx._source.comments.add(params.emp)",
            params: {
                emp: {
                     empId: 'xyz1234',
                     empDetail: {
                                  name: 'ss',
                     },
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the type of `comments` field?

Comment: sorry, its typo ,it should be emp

Comment: OK what field is it? Object?

Comment: @Lefteris yes its object